# Using GWT as portlets for google sites?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-gadget, google-sites

Is it possible to use GWT as a framework for building portlets that are rendered in google sites?

If so, I'm assuming that these portlets could just be hosted on a GAE instance?

On another point, GWT is java based, but what if portlets are written in python? I'm assuming Django can be rendered into a google site gadget?

thanks

paul

Comment: Sites supports the gadgets api, which can be used with Gwt.

Answer (score 1):

a portlet for a Google site would per definition be a Google Gadget.

A Google gadget is basically a piece of HTML and/or javascript, along with a accompanying XML specification. for more info see http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/reference.html.

- Yes you can host the HTML/javavscript and XML spec on Google
  Appengine.
- Yes you can write Google Gadget using GWT see also [GWT gadgets](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/reference.html)
- Yes you can write gadgets using Django as long as you generate a
  valid HTML/javascript and XML spec using Django